# "I'm never coming here ever again" or "i will never come here ever again"

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, tense

I wonder which one is correct to use

> I'm never coming here ever again
>   I will never come here ever again

And if both of them is correct which one is more commonly used ?

Answer (score 1):

Both are quite acceptable ways of expressing a future intent, and there is no significant difference in meaning.

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20am%20never%20coming%2C%20I%20will%20never%20come&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20am%20never%20coming%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20will%20never%20come%3B%2Cc0) shows that the "I will never..." form is about five times as common.